# Equations Match the Columns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=2x^3-9x^2-24x+p,\quad p\in\mathbb R$

Match the columns

1. $f(x)$ has three distinct real roots, then p belongs to
2. $f(x)$ has two positive roots and one negative root, then p belongs to
3. $f(x)$ has two negative roots and one positive root, then p belongs to
4. $f(x)$ has only one real root, then p belongs to

---

- $(-13, 112)$
- $(0, 112)$
- $(-13, 0)$
- $(113,+\infty)$
- $(-\infty, -14)$

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Which ones do you know match? Which ones do you know _not_ match?

Comment: Hint:calculus might help here.Also the problem looks very much like some previous year IIT JEE problem.

Comment: @Arthur, I tried solving 4. I assumed that the graph of the equation should cut the X-axis only once. But I couldn't decide whether there would be a maxima and a minima in the graph. If both should exist, then f'(x)=0 giving x=4,-1. Since both the maxima and the minima should be either above the X-axis or below it, f(4)f(-1)>0, giving (p+13)(p-112)>0, that is, p belongs to (-infinity, -14) union (113, infinity). Couldn't get the other ones though.

Comment: Well, number 1 follows a very similar train of thought, and you've already done most of the calculations for it already. Also, whatever value of $p$ you choose doesn't at all affect whether or not there are maxima or minima, or even where on the $x$-axis they appear. Since $p$ is just a constant term, changing it only shifts the graph up and down.

Comment: For 2. and 3., try to figure out when one of the zeros is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: I guess for 1., (p+13)(p-112)<0 giving p belongs to (-13, 112). But I am still unclear on 2. and 3. Please elaborate. Also specify whether I am right.